# C# Delegate Event handler does not work?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling, anonymous-function

I am writing some test function for my application. 

In this piece of test code, I create a file stream from local Json file and deserialize that using my own wrapped `JsonDeserializer` class.

```
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            JsonDeserializer<People>.DeserializeStream(fs);
            JsonDeserializer<People>.DeserializeEvent += new EventHandler<DeserializeEventArgs<People>>(
                delegate(object sender, DeserializeEventArgs<People> e) 
                {
                    id = e.DeserializeResult.Id;
                });
        }
```

And in my JsonDeseralizer class, it will raise an event when deserializing finished like this:

```
        using (Stream readyToDeserializeStream = new MemoryStream(readyToDeserializeByteArray))
        {

            DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

            T resultObject = (T)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(readyToDeserializeStream);

            if (DeserializeEvent != null) <-----this is null
            {
                DeserializeEvent(null, new DeserializeEventArgs<T>(resultObject));
            }
        }
```

But the problem is in the first code piece, even if I added the handler to the event, it still turn out to be the event is null(in the second code piece). So I am wondering if I did the delegate event handler and the anonymous function wrong in the first part?

Please share your idea about this, thank you.

=================Update======================

Defination of the DeserializeEvent in JsonDeserializer class

```
 public static event EventHandler<DeserializeEventArgs<T>> DeserializeEvent;
```

Comment: Is `DeserializeEvent` a *static* event? Are you definitely using `JsonDeserialized<People>`? A short but *complete* program would be helpful here.

Comment: What library is `JsonDeserializer` located in?

Comment: Where's your delegate for the DeserializeEvent? We need to see that as well.

Comment: The program is pretty long but I can paste more here.

Comment: @JonSkeet `DeserializeEvent` is a static event

Comment: @AllanJiang: I didn't ask you for your complete existing program, just a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. You should isolate the problem until you've got a program which is as short as possible, but still shows it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for your comment, but I think the code is enough to demonstrate my problem. The first piece of code is just a test program that attach a handler to the static event and handle the event use anonymous function. Everything else is no problem, and I can use a normal handler method to work well. Nothing serious with the Json deserializer, just wondering what cause the handler can not be attached to the event (as shown in the second piece of code, the event is empty.) Thank you

Comment: @AllanJiang: Well it isn't really... and the fact that you haven't had an answer yet suggests that too. For example, if `T` isn't `People` at that point, you're going to have subscribed to a different eventhandler... but we have no idea what's going on. As an aside, I would strongly advise *against* using static events, but that's a separate matter. (I'd suggest you should create an *instance* of `JsonSerializer` when you want one. All kinds of things are nicer without global state.)

Comment: Why are you subscribing the event *after* calling DeserializeStream()?

Comment: @JonSkeet Good suggestion, I will refactor my code later to make it better, but Hans gives the right solution. Thank you anyways